# What is the fastest way to find a subsequence of a given sequence that every element before is less and every element after is greater

Tags: algorithm, subsequence

What is the fastest way to find a subsequence of a given sequence under the condition that for each element `x` in the subsequence, every element in the given sequence before `x` is less than `x` and every element in the given sequence after `x` is greater than `x`?

Sample input

```
9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 5, 2, 20, 25, 30, 80, 90, 100, 50, 40, 41
```

Sample output

```
20, 25, 30
```

Comment: Would `5 4 3` in `1 5 4 3 7` qualify as such a subsequence? (i.e. does the subsequence itself have to be ascending?)

Comment: Why not just return the whole sequence?

Comment: @Amadan Updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with your sequence and construct maximums to the left, minimums to the right:

```
  9,   8,   7,   6,   5,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  10,   5,   2,  20,  25,  30,  80,  90, 100,  50,  40,  41
  9,   9,   9,   9,   9,   9,   9,  10,  11,  12,  12,  12,  12,  20,  25,  30,  80,  90, 100, 100, 100, 100
  2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,  20,  25,  30,  40,  40,  40,  40,  40,  41
```

Pull out the ones where the three arrays match.  In this case `20, 25, 30`.

This takes time and memory `O(n)`.

Comment: Could you explain how this would take O(n) Time, please?

Comment: @Carlton Building up the maximums is a forward pass in time `O(n)`.  Building up the minimums is a backwards pass in time `O(n)`.  And looking for all matching is another `O(n)` pass. `O(n + n + n) = O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!